# SNMP on Linux (Centos) not showing load average

Tags: centos, snmp, centos5

I installed SNMP on my Linux in order to monitory load balance, disk space etc.

```
yum install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
vim /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf   # added "rocommunity  public"
/etc/init.d/snmpd start
```

Walking the SNMP returns very few entries, no load average, disk space etc.:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost

SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux XXX 2.6.35.4-rscloud #8 SMP Mon Sep 20 15:54:33 UTC 2010 x86_64
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpAgentOIDs.10
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (232884) 0:38:48.84
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmp.local.conf)
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: XXX
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: Unknown (edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf)
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.1 = OID: SNMPv2-MIB::snmpMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.2 = OID: TCP-MIB::tcpMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.3 = OID: IP-MIB::ip
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.4 = OID: UDP-MIB::udpMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.5 = OID: SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB::vacmBasicGroup
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.6 = OID: SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpFrameworkMIBCompliance
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.7 = OID: SNMP-MPD-MIB::snmpMPDCompliance
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.8 = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmMIBCompliance
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.1 = STRING: The MIB module for SNMPv2 entities
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.2 = STRING: The MIB module for managing TCP implementations
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.3 = STRING: The MIB module for managing IP and ICMP implementations
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.4 = STRING: The MIB module for managing UDP implementations
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.5 = STRING: View-based Access Control Model for SNMP.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.6 = STRING: The SNMP Management Architecture MIB.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.7 = STRING: The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.8 = STRING: The management information definitions for the SNMP User-based Security Model.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.1 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.2 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.3 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.4 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.5 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.6 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.7 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.8 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

1. needed to reset the .conf file completely:

   echo "rocommunity  public" > /etc/snmp/snmp.conf
2. needed to specify the exact branch to walk:

   snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.10

Answer (score 0):

For others like me who might search for this:

It is due to the rocommunity being restricted to basic access in the default SNMPd config with the line:

```
rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
```

To give full access to localhost just uncomment the previous line which is:

```
rocommunity public  localhost
```

Or you can give all computers full access like OP did via:

```
rocommunity public
```